# I want to drop rows In my data frame base on column 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
Column1.          Column2

Start1                   633

End.                       855

Start2.                     767

Start3.                      231

End.                           545

Start4.                      111

Start5                       243

End.                           333
```

Output

```
Column1.          Column2

Start1                   633

End.                       855

Start3.                      231

End.                           545

Start5                       243

End.                           333
```

In column1 Start2 row drop because it's not end same as start4

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` and groupby like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['Start1','End.','Start2','Start3','End.','Start4','Start5','End.'],
                   'Column2':[633,855,767,231,545,111,243,333]})
```

Input dataframe:

```
  Column1  Column2
0  Start1      633
1    End.      855
2  Start2      767
3  Start3      231
4    End.      545
5  Start4      111
6  Start5      243
7    End.      333
```

Use  cumsum and groupby:

```
df[df.groupby((df['Column1'] != 'End.').cumsum())['Column1'].transform('count') == 2]
```

Output:

```
  Column1  Column2
0  Start1      633
1    End.      855
3  Start3      231
4    End.      545
6  Start5      243
7    End.      333
```

Answer (score 0):

It is longer than the previous answer but I Believe it is more understandable:

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
## Create the Dataframe
cols = ['Column1', 'Column2']
data = [['Start1', 633],['End', 855],['Start2', 767],['Start3', 231],
        ['End', 545],['Start4', 111],['Start5', 243],['End', 333]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
df

Out [1]:
    Column1 Column2
0   Start1  633
1   End     855
2   Start2  767
3   Start3  231
4   End     545
5   Start4  111
6   Start5  243
7   End     333
```

Here I loop on the rows and if the rows after contains as well `Start` I delete the row.

```py
In [2]:
idx = df.index.tolist()
droped_idx = []
for i in idx[:-1]:
    row = df.iloc[i, 0]
    next_row = df.iloc[i+1, 0]
    if (('Start' in row) & ('Start' in next_row)):
        droped_idx.append(i)

df.drop(index=droped_idx, inplace=True)
df

Out [2]:
    Column1 Column2
0   Start1  633
1   End     855
3   Start3  231
4   End     545
6   Start5  243
7   End     333
```